# TCP listening on port (tcpip) without root and usb cable on android < 11

Tags: android, adb, port, tcpserver, usb-debugging

On Android 11 and above it's available the option "Wireless debugging", so no problem there.
However, on Android 10 and below there is no option for wireless debugging. In order to make the client listen on a specific port, we need to manually execute `tcpip 5555`.

There are two option as far as I know:

- Executing `tcpip 5555` directly on the target device (android) with root permissions.
- Executing `adb tcpip 5555` from another device with an usb cable.

Question:

is it possible, on Android 10 and below, to listen on a port (for debug purposes) without root permission or an usb cable from another device?

Comment: To my knowledge only the two ways exists that you describe in your question.

Comment: Yes, possible. Just open a ServerSocket for that port.

Comment: So, executing tcpip 5555 would be the equivalent of opening a ServerSocket on port 5555? I am asking because I am not sure how I would need to replicate the adb server, more specifically how to handle the strings that I would receive on the socket.

Comment: @blackapps As far as I know the port 5555 is not open unless you execute `tcpip 5555` on the device. So how should open up a port help to get a working adb connection?

Comment: Sorry, i should not have commented as it was not to the point not knowing where you were after, sorry.