# Where can I find the source of command tcpip on android? Is it possible to replicate the behaviour without root?

Tags: java, android, adb, serversocket, tcpserver

As I asked here: [TCP listening on port (tcpip) without root and usb cable on android < 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866936/tcp-listening-on-port-tcpip-without-root-and-usb-cable-on-android-11?noredirect=1#comment130435394_73866936)

I am trying to listen on a specific port (without root or usb cable) for running commands through adb. Someone, in the comments of the previous question, suggested that I could open a ServerSocket on port 5555. I am asking because I am not sure how I would need to replicate the adb server, more specifically how to handle the strings that I would receive on the socket.

So, as mentioned in the title, I would like to take a peek at the source of the command tcpip an replicate, if possible, the behaviour without needing root.

Comment: you may not even need to implement that, https://github.com/vidstige/jadb - it should also contain a lot of information about the protocol (which someone documented https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation ), I'm just not sure the adb server side is exposed in a way that allows clients from within.

Comment: You will need `adb` to give the needed permission to your `fake-adb` for it to be able to do something useful (*if your intention is to create a new one as the question seems to indicate*)